# How can I create the following data type in Python?

Tags: python

How can I define a data type the can hold the following data.

```
{ "id": {"sub_id": ["x","x2"], "sub_id_2": ["x3", "x4"]},
  "id2": {"sub_id": ["x","x2"], "sub_id_2": ["x3", "x4"]}
}
```

Comment: It appears that you have created a dictionary.

Comment: what are you creating it *from*? If you just want that literal dictionary (of dictionaries of lists), then just write it as written. otherwise what data do you need to convert to this structure?

Comment: A dictionary can hold the data that you're showing us.  Creating a new datatype (class) would not allow you to use that syntax and is unlikely to improve clarity or performance.  Specifically, if all you're doing is holding information, use a dictionary; if you want a datatype that includes methods to be performed on that information, write a class that contains a dictionary.  Which are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `defaultdict` whose default value is a `defaultdict(list)` might work well for building this structure:

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydata = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
```

[Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Then you add data as needed like this:

```
mydata['id']['sub_id'].append('x')
mydata['id']['sub_id_2'].append('x3')
mydata['id2']['sub_id'].append('x')
mydata['id']['sub_id_2'].append('x4')
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the default value of an item in your defaultdict to be the dictionary you describe, you can do so as follows:

```
default_data = { "id": {"sub_id": ["x","x2"], "sub_id_2": ["x3", "x4"]},
            "id2": {"sub_id": ["x","x2"], "sub_id_2": ["x3", "x4"]}
          }
my_data = defaultdict(lambda: default_data)
```